# RestEasy client can't use @PathParam argument

Tags: java, rest, testing, junit, resteasy

My test fails when trying to check my @GET method.

The method:

```
@GET
@Path("{eventId}")
public Response getEvent(@PathParam("eventId") String eventId){
    return Response.ok(this.event.getEventFromId(eventId)).build();
}
```

The test:

```
@Test
@InSequence(11)
@Header(name = "Authorization", value = "Basic cGFibG86cGFibG9wYWJsbw==")
@RunAsClient
public void testGetEventById(@ArquillianResteasyResource(BASE_PATH + "{eventId}") ResteasyWebTarget webTarget) {
    final Response response = webTarget.queryParam("eventId", "1").request().get();

    assertThat(response, hasOkStatus());

    final Event Event = EventType.readEntity(response);

    Assert.assertNotNull(Event);
}
```

If I put the method this way, the test works.

```
@GET
@Path("eventId")
public Response getEvent(){
    return Response.ok(this.event.getEventFromId("1")).build();
}
```

Sorry for my bad English.
Thks

Comment: Seems like you are adding `URL parameter` rather than `Path Paramter` when you use `webTarget.queryParam`

Answer (score 0):

You might have confused from PathParam and Query Params.
PathParam is `url/{eventId}/...`
Where Query Param is `url?eventId=1`
When you write `return Response.ok(this.event.getEventFromId("1")).build();
}` you are actually hardcoding the request so any request would always use 1 as a value, I don't think that is your desired effect.